# CSS3 label tag facing right and using position or :after

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

I am trying to construct this shape in CSS:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to put the triangle shape (considering I have a rectangle for the "body" of the tag and a triangle for the tip) facing right. Because I'm working with positions, how can I tell the triangle to appear right after the rectangle, when tags can all have different sizes? I just can't work it out.

You can check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ExZFe/ with a similar tag to the one I'm making. This example uses just positions, so giving the triangle a fixed position is useless. I tried with :after but got stuck too, because of the same reason. What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply position the triangle using the `right` property (which start from the right of the rectangle) instead of the `left` (which starts from the *left* of the rectangle and is useless here as you can't know the width of the tags): http://jsfiddle.net/Gv3rf/

Comment: Thanks powerbuoy! That was quick!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line-height to .tag

```
.tag {
line-height: 10px;
/* the rest of your styles here */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExZFe/3/

Comment: Oh... I thought you wanted verticle alignment so the triangle and text area looked like one. I now realize that you wanted the arrow's position to be on the other side.